# CSOM - file.DeleteObject() doesn't delete file

Tags: document-library, csom, delete

am trying to do a simple operation "Delete file from document library using CSOM"
As i have only the Relative path `http://hostname/subsite/subsite/doclibname/sample.docx`

I used below code to get the File object and then delete it.

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(relativePath);                    
clientContext.Load(file);
file.DeleteObject();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

The code executes without errors. However the file doesn't get deleted.

Googled for it. Getting solutions of using LibraryName. However in real scenario i won't be getting the document library name. I will be just getting URL.

Kindly advise.

Comment: It seems issue of the file path only. What is the full path you are passing in "relativePath" variable ? Try accessing "file.Name" after loading file, to verify that you are able to load the file using URL. Yashesh Nagori

Comment: Hi Yahesh, Thank you for your reply. I added "ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();" line after Load() and checked for File.Name it is showing File name.
The value for "relativePath" is "Departments/IT/testdoclib/sample.docx"

Kindly advise

Comment: Note: _If the file does not exist, the Delete method silently fails and does not throw a FileNotFoundException_ So try and load: `.Load(file, f => f.Exists);` and check the property after execute

Comment: Hi Andres, i checked in the document library itself. It is there as it is.

Comment: No... You are supposed to check in CSOM if you can access the file before deleting it, not the UI

Comment: Hi Heiko, 
I checked with   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(relativePath);                    clientContext.Load(file,f => f.Exists);                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();                    
bool exists = file.Exists;          
 file.DeleteObject();                    
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


Executed the function 2 times. Both the time it returns true

Answer (score 1):

Please use relative path as:
"/subsite/subsite/doclibname/sample.docx".

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/subsite/subsite/doclibname/sample.docx");
```

You are passing absolute path and trying to get file using relative one.